# Word puzzle. Guess the word

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Various metals and paints are used to bring me to my current form.
>   At times I'm lonely and at times I become very popular.
>   I'm very useful and you've definitely seen me at least once in your life.
>   You cannot find me in your house.
>   Reverse the word and all the above still hold true.

**What am I?**

Note:- I'm **not** a palindrome. If you reverse me you do **not** get the same word.

Comment: So I'm leaving it as is. People (at least I) rarely see the edit history :)

Comment: Cheap Answer: Depending on your definition of useful, you could be a racecar!

Comment: @TwoBitOperation Red rum, sir, is murder hahaha also radar fulfill  xD

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo The 'algorithm' you mentioned could be applied to ANY riddle - in fact, that's the best way to solve riddles, short of 'random inspiration'.

Comment: @TwoBitOperation I had racecar in mind while making the riddle. But a palindrome would become too easy. Wouldn't it :)

Comment: "Reverse the word and all the above still hold true" suggests to me one of two things: (1) There are two equally valid answers to the riddle, one being the other spelled in reverse; (2) The answer is a palindrome. If we assume a unique answer, then "racecar" fits the first and last clues, but the others not so much. (Wow, the OP posted mere seconds before me and has just ruled my answer out.)

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo I saw it earlier while not logged in :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are a

> **Bus**

Various metals and paints are used to bring me to my current form.

> Buses are made of metal and paint.

At times I'm lonely and at times I become very popular.

> Sometimes there are lots of people on the bus, sometimes not.

I'm very useful and you've definitely seen me at least once in your life.

> Buses are definitely useful and almost everyone has seen one.

You cannot find me in your house.

> That would be awkward.

Reverse the word and all the above still hold true.

> A **sub** (submarine) is another thing you wouldn't see in your house, made of metal and paints, sometimes full sometimes not, and is useful and most have likely seen on at least in a movie/TV show.

---

Note that you could also make basically the same arguments for

> **Tram** / **Mart**

Comment: But many people have never seen a submarine in their lives - or a tram, for that matter.

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah, for this to be right "seen" needs to include on TV, movies, etc., as I said.

Comment: Nice! Tram is the expected answer. Trams and trains are very similar. The only difference being distance covered and the tracks. The question never stated that you've seen it in real life :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> a SLOOP / POOLS?

Various metals and paints are used to bring me to my current form.

> A sloop is made of various painted metal components, as are swimming pools.

At times I'm lonely and at times I become very popular.

> Either one is empty when not used, and can be full of people at other times.

I'm very useful and you've definitely seen me at least once in your life.

> Sloops are useful for sailing in, and pools are useful for swimming in. Everyone's seen a pool, and quite possibly a sloop.

You cannot find me in your house.

> Both things are found out of doors.

Reverse the word and all the above still hold true.

> Reverse SLOOP and you get POOLS.

Comment: Awesome answer. If nobody gets closer, this shall be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Decal?  Backwards is laced. Both can be made of paints and metals.

Or are you a

> Nametag?  Backwards is gateman.  Both should be outside your house. Both can be lonely until the time they are used. But I can find a Nametag in my house.

Comment: Nice try. And metal plays no factor to get to the current form. You deserve an upvote though.

Answer (score 0):

Various metals and paints are used to bring me to my current form.

> Body

You cannot find me in your house.

> Huge

The answer is:

> Aeroplane or a Ship

Comment: How would that fit the last line of the riddle?

Comment: The last line is the most important part else it would be too broad a riddle.